# How can I use an already installed module when I'm using a virtual environment?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, i2c, modules

I have created a virtual enviroment on my RPI3 (Raspbian-Jessie), so that I may more easily work with a particular image-searching software [(as outlined in this tutorial, step #4)](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/).

My script requires a module, "smbus", to use I2C while running a **python 2.7** script in my virtual environment.
The issue is that I can't import the module when the environment is activated, and I can't install in within the environment.

Code:

`import smbus`

Shell:

`(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python i2ctest1.py`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "i2ctest1.py", line 1, in <module>`
`import smbus`
**`ImportError: No module named smbus`**

It will however import just fine outside that "cv" environment. I can see the module installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip freeze
[...]
smbus==1.1
[...]
```

But inside the environment, smbus is not there:

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip freeze
imutils==0.3.6
numpy==1.11.1
picamera==1.12
Shapely==1.5.17
spidev==3.2
```

I tried installing smbus with the environment activated, but it just tells me it is already installed:

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python-smbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-smbus is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
```

I also tried :
`(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install smbus`

resulting in:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): smbus in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install smbus --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: smbus in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I read this [link on virtual environments](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/), but I was not able to understand what I've done wrong.

*Do I need to install the module differently, or do I just need to import it differently?*

Comment: I think this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages

Comment: I have already created my environment, and cannot create another one. Thus I *think* the answers to that Q don't apply.